# Is there any way to check downloads without UI (Mac / Unix)

Tags: macos, shell, unix, applescript

I am looking for a way to check if there are downloads in the system without using the UI (Shell, Apple Script, Cocoa etc.)
For example, when I download a file in safari, then I want to check if this download is still running without using the UI. So far I have found no possibility, maybe someone can help me here?

Edit:
I have found a way to check if processes are running. Maybe there is a process for downloads or for safari downloads? But which?

Comment: In which program?

Comment: safari would be the most important. Or if u mean in which program i want to check it, then terminal

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about other applications, but Safari downloads have a file extension of "download" until the download is finished, so you could check for that.

**AppleScript**:

```
tell application "System Events" to get files of (path to downloads folder) whose name extension is "download"
```

**Terminal**:

```
find ~/Downloads -name "*.download"
```

Comment: great idea, but the problem is there, that I see also the files were the download was canceled, but i want to see only the running downloads

Comment: Each application would handle downloads however it wants, so there may not be a separate process for it. **curl** doesn't do that, for example.  You could add in something like a check for file sizes or modification dates.